# Schoofs Algorithm

Tags: elliptic-curves, group-theory

I studied [Schoofs Algorithm described by Washington](https://people.cs.nctu.edu.tw/%7Erjchen/ECC2012S/Elliptic%20Curves%20Number%20Theory%20And%20Cryptography%202n.pdf).

[On page 125](https://people.cs.nctu.edu.tw/%7Erjchen/ECC2012S/Elliptic%20Curves%20Number%20Theory%20And%20Cryptography%202n.pdf#page=125) he says that we could write $y'/y$ as a function of $x$, which makes sense since earlier on the page he denotes $y'= r_{2,j}(x)y$.

But I can't find any definition of $r_{2,j}(x)$ although he referenced p.47. So what would be the definition of $r_{2,j}(x)$?

Comment: Note I've looked at the [errata for edition 2](http://www.math.umd.edu/~lcw/ECerrata2.pdf) but not listed.

Comment: Your second link goes to page 112, not 125. page 125 of the book is page 138 of the pdf. I did not see the statement you're referencing on either page, so I'm not sure which is the correct one.

Comment: I'm sorry, the links were edited. But @kelalaka helped a lot. It is in deed listed at the errata section. The reference to page 47 seemed to be false, instead page 51 would be correct.

Comment: Oh, I missed that :)

Comment: Post an answer and close it?